# Элемент не отображается внутри блока

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Всем привет! Не могу понять почему список будто за пределами блока.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #2F3136;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.header1 {
  padding: 1px 0px 0px 4px;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
  color: #A6A7A8;
  height: 22px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #202225;
  border: 2px solid #202225;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
}

.leftside {
  background: #202225;
  border: 2px solid #202225;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 27px;
  width: 80px;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='ru'>
<head>
  <title>мм</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='header1'>Discord</div>
  <div class='leftside'>
    <ul>
      <ol>*фото*</ol>
      <ol>*фото*</ol>
      <ol>*фото*</ol>
      <ol>*фото*</ol>
      <ol>*фото*</ol>
      <ol>*фото*</ol>
      <ol>*фото*</ol>
      <ol>*фото*</ol>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из за стандартных маргинов и паддингов, вы так-же почему-то поставили `ol` вместо `li`

```css
*
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #2F3136;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.header1 {
  padding: 1px 0px 0px 4px;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
  color: #A6A7A8;
  height: 22px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #202225;
  border: 2px solid #202225;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
}

.leftside {
  background: #202225;
  border: 2px solid #202225;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 27px;
  width: 80px;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='ru'>
<head>
  <title>мм</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='header1'>Discord</div>
  <div class='leftside'>
    <ul>
      <li>*фото*</li>
      <li>*фото*</li>
      <li>*фото*</li>
      <li>*фото*</li>
      <li>*фото*</li>
      <li>*фото*</li>
      <li>*фото*</li>
      <li>*фото*</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```